# Cómo refactorizar objetos que comparten propiedades y/o metodos

Tags: javascript

Imagina que tengo 2 objetos:

```
var coche1= {
  marca: "Seat",
  modelo: "Ibiza",
  aceleracion: function(){a+b} 
};

var coche2= {
  marca: "Skoda",
  modelo: "Fabia",
  aceleracion: function(){a+b} //mismo método que coche1.aceleracion()
};
```

¿Existe alguna forma de crear un objeto "padre" o prototipo que tenga ese método, y así luego crear los objetos `coche1` y `coche2` a partir de él, que compartan ese método además de tener los suyos propios? y, ¿merece la pena hacerlo, o hay veces que es mejor dejarlo así?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te dejo el código de mi respuesta anterior en un Snippet todo comentado que espero que sirva para comprender mejor la respuesta.

```js
// Declaro el constructor
function Coche(marca = "Seat", modelo = "Ibiza") {
  // Si marca y modelo no fueron enviador por parametro se utiliza los valores por defecto "Seat" y "Ibiza" respectivamente
  this.marca = marca;
  this.modelo = modelo;
}

// Declaro un metodo
Coche.prototype.aceleracion = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
};


var coche1 = new Coche(); // Tendra marca y modelo por defecto
var coche2 = new Coche(); // Tendra marca y modelo por defecto

var coche3 = new Coche("Ford", "Fiesta"); // Tendra marca y modelo personalizados


console.log(coche1.marca); // Imprimo la marca en consola
console.log(coche2.aceleracion(5, 10)); // Imprimo el resultado del método
console.log(coche3.modelo);
```

Para más información te recomiendo leer este [documento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introducci%C3%B3n_a_JavaScript_orientado_a_objetos) sobre orientación a objectos en Javascript.

Espero haber sido de ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: @Genarito Gracias por tu respuesta, pero tengo una duda: en tu respuesta estás generando un prototipo sólo con las propiedades de coche1, o lo he entendido mal?

Comment: @Pablo se puede usar prototipo cuando se desea crear propiedades y/o métodos comunes a todos los objetos instanciados a partir del constructor. El beneficio de esto es ahorro de memoria y la posibilidad de mutar todas las instancias al mismo tiempo al modificar el prototipo del constructor. Cabe destacar que `marca` y `modelo`, son propios de cada instancia por lo que esta bien que no estén en el prototipo.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo Gracias Marcos, he estado buscando más informacion y ahora ya entiendo lo que dices, no estaba entendiendo la respuesta de Genarito. El que hubiera una funcion como constructor no me habia quedado claro.

Comment: Gracias @MarcosGallardo por la observación, ahí corregí ese y otros errores, y también te agradezco por la información sobre la sentencia `prototype`, no podrías haberlo explicado mejor. Espero que las dudas se hayan resuelto @Pablo cualquier cosa nos avisas! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Complementado un poco lo de @Genarito con un ejemplo funcional:

```js
// Declaro el constructor
function Coche(marca,modelo) {
 this.marca=marca;
 this.modelo=modelo;

 // Declaro un metodo
 this.aceleracion=function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
 };
}


var coche1 = new Coche("Seat","Ibiza");
var coche2 = new Coche("Skoda","Fabia");
console.log(coche1.marca+" "+coche1.modelo+" "+coche1.aceleracion(4,5));
console.log(coche2.marca+" "+coche2.modelo+" "+coche2.aceleracion(40,50));
```

Comment: ¿Doy por hecho que esto se considera una buena práctica mejor que dejarlo duplicado como en mi ejemplo?

Comment: Tarde pero seguro! Claramente es una excelente práctica: tener código repetido es inmantenible, imaginate que tenés que realizar un cambio y se quiere cambiar el comportamiento del método `aceleracion()`, en el código de nuestra respuesta solo tendrias que cambiar un solo método, en tu caso tendrías que cambiar tantos métodos como autos tengas, si tenés 100 entonces vas a tener que cambiar 100 métodos!

Comment: Ni hablar de la cantidad de líneas de código que dificultaría la lectura y/o entendimiento de lo que hiciste para futuros cambios

Answer (score 0):

Aprovecho para actualizar la respuesta de @genarito utilizando las clases de javascript añadidas en la última versión ECMASCRIPT 6.

```
class Coche {
  constructor (marca = "Seat", modelo = "Ibiza"){
    // Si marca y modelo no fueron enviados por parámetro se utilizan los valores por defecto "Seat" y "Ibiza" respectivamente
    this.marca = marca;
    this.modelo = modelo;
  }

  aceleracion (a, b){
    return a + b;
  }
};

const coche1 = new Coche(); // Tendrá marca y modelo por defecto
const coche2 = new Coche(); // Tendrá marca y modelo por defecto
const coche3 = new Coche("Ford", "Fiesta"); // Tendrá marca y modelo personalizados


console.log(coche1.marca); // Seat
console.log(coche2.aceleracion(5, 10)); // 15
console.log(coche3.modelo); // Fiesta
```

Comment: En realidad siguen siendo funciones constructoras con prototipo :)

Comment: @Gustavo García Si, ya sé que es lo mismo :). En realidad me he autorespondido porque así lo veo más claro, y para tenerlo como referencia en el futuro jaja

Comment: jaja esta sintaxis es muy buena para los programadores acostumbrados a Java, C# o PHP :) Y en un futuro es muy probable que añadan cosas como variables privadas y anotaciones (de hecho ya están hechas las propuestas).